# Paginador Laravel, no funciona en respuesta AJAX

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola tras varios días de intentarlo y con ayuda de gente de este foro y no poder solucionarlo, voy a publicar el contenido a ver si alguien sabe que sucede.

He creado un filtrador con checkboxes y un buscador, este hace una petición ajax y según la respuesta me devuelve los productos que toca.
El problema viene siendo que a costado un montón mostrar el paginador, pero una vez mostrado no funciona. Muestro el código y luego explico.

**AJAX que se encarga de hacer las peticiones**

```
// Ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el DOM
  $(function() {
    // Asignar evento a checkboxes
    $('[name="categoria[]"], [name="subcategoria[]"], [name="marcas[]"], [name="genero[]"], #search').bind('click keyup', function(event) {
        cargarProductos();
    });
    // Ejecutar cuando carga el DOM
    //cargarProductos();
  });

  // Función para petición AJAX
  function cargarProductos() {
    $value= $("#search").val();
    var categoria = $('[name="categoria[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    var subcategoria = $('[name="subcategoria[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    var marca = $('[name="marcas[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    var genero = $('[name="genero[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    
    var url = 'productos';
    $.ajax({
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {'categoria': categoria,
            'subcategoria': subcategoria,
            'marca' : marca,
            'genero' : genero,
            'search':$value },

            beforeSend: function(){
              $("#filtrados").html("<div id='loader'></div>")
            },
              timeout:500000,
            success: function (resultado){
                setTimeout(function(){ $("#filtrados").html(resultado); }, 1000); 
            },
            error: function(e) { $("#filtrados").html("Sucedió un error!") }
    });
  };
```

**El controlador**

```
public function filtros(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->only("categoria", "subcategoria", "marca", "search", 'genero');
        
        $filtrador = Product::with('variaciones')
                ->join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategoria', '=', 'subcategories.id')
                ->join('marcas', 'products.proveedor', '=', 'marcas.id')
                ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nameCategoria', 'subcategories.name as nameSubcategoria', 'marcas.empresa as proveedor');

                //verificamos que exista y contenga almenos 1 dato
                if(isset($data["categoria"]) && count($data["categoria"])){
                    $filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn('products.categoria', $data["categoria"]);
                }

                //verificamos que exista y contenga almenos 1 dato
                if(isset($data["subcategoria"]) && count($data["subcategoria"])){
                    $filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn('products.subcategoria', $data["subcategoria"]);
                }

                if(isset($data["marca"]) && count($data["marca"])){
                    $filtrador = $filtrador->whereIn('products.proveedor', $data["marca"]);
                }

                if($request->ajax()){
                    $filtrador = $filtrador->where('products.name', 'LIKE','%'.$request->search."%");
                }

                //solo como ejemplo, en caso de obtener el ultimo
                $last = "";
                if($last){
                $filtrador = $filtrador->latest('id');
                }else{
                //o devolver la lista
                $filtrador = $filtrador->paginate(6);
                }
                
                $filtradorHtml = "";
                

                foreach($filtrador->items() as $pro){
                    $filtradorHtml .= "<div class=\"col-4\">
                    <div class=\"cardProduct\">
                      <div>
                        <div style=\"position: relative\">";
                          if ($pro->foto == null){
                            $filtradorHtml .= "<img src=\"images/no-foto.jpg\"  class=\"imgProduct\">";
                          }else{
                            $filtradorHtml .= "<img src=\"$pro->foto\"  class=\"imgProduct\">";  
                          }
          
                    $filtradorHtml .= " 
                        <div class=\"etiqueta3estados\">";
                            if ($pro->estado == 1){
                                $filtradorHtml .= "<span class=\"publicado\">Publicado</span>"; 
                            }elseif ($pro->estado == 2){   
                                $filtradorHtml .= "<span class=\"noPubli\">No publicado</span>";
                            }elseif ($pro->estado == 3){
                                $filtradorHtml .= " <span class=\"borrador\">Borrador</span>";
                            }
                    $filtradorHtml .= " 
                        </div>
                          <div class=\"posicionPapelera\" id=\"posicionPapelera\">
                            <a href=\"\"><i class=\"far fa-edit eyeProduct\"></i></a>
                            <a href=\"\"><i class=\"far fa-trash-alt eyeProduct\"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>        
                        <div class=\"mgTop9\">
                          <div class=\"marcaDiv\">
                             $pro->proveedor
                            <span class=\"pull-right refeProduct\"> $pro->referencia </span>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class=\"productTitle\"> $pro->name </div>
                          <div class=\"cardpProduct\"> $pro->descripcion</div>
                          <div class=\"dropdown-divider margb4\"></div>
                          <div class=\"row targCate\">
                              <div class=\"col-6\">
                                  <h5>Categoría</h5>
                                  <span> $pro->nameCategoria </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class=\"col-6\">
                                  <h5>Subcategoria</h5>
                                  <span> $pro->nameSubcategoria </span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class=\"lasOpt\">
                            <div>
                                <h5>Genero:</h5>
                                <span>";
                                foreach($pro->variaciones as $varia){
                                    if ($varia->variant == 'genero'){
                                        $filtradorHtml .= "$varia->valor";
                                    }
                                }    
                    $filtradorHtml .= "</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                          <div class=\"dropdown-divider margb4\"></div>
                          <a href=\"\" class=\"btn btnGuardar corrigeBtNverproducto\">Ver producto</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>";
                }
                
                if($filtradorHtml == '') { $filtradorHtml = 'No hay productos, o el mensaje que quieras que aparezca'; }

                $filtradorHtml .= "<div class=\"container center margBlog1 pull-right\" style=\"padding: 0;\">";
                $filtradorHtml .= $filtrador->links(); 
                $filtradorHtml .= "</div>";
                

        return $filtradorHtml;
    }
```

Esto se encarga de hacer las comprobaciones y retornar los valores necesarios. Funciona bien y muestra el paginador.

**Script del paginador**

```
  /*$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    // if hash in url
    if (window.location.hash) {
        // page contains hash value
        var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        // if ok ->getData returned
        else {
            getData(page);
        }
    }
});*/

$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.pagination li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
    console.log("Url: " + url);
    getData(page,url);
});

function getData(page,url) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#filtrados').empty().html(data);
            /*location.hash = page;*/
        },
        fail: function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('No response from server');
        }
    });
}
```

Luego está este JavaScript para que funcione el paginador.

Bien, el problema está en varios puntos. En el primer AJAX tengo esto `cargarProductos();` que ahora esta comentado. Esto me vale para que cuando cargo la página automáticamente cargue el ajax. Pero eso en la consola hace que me cargue un `productos` que es la plantilla y luego otro `productos` que son los resultados.

Antes de comentar `cargaProductos();` si le daba a la página 2, me cargaba en la consola `productos?page=2` donde en preview me salia la plantilla y seguido de eso otra vez `productos` con los resultados, pero me salian otra vez los de la página 1.

Entonces decidi comentar `cargaProductos();` para que no cargase al iniciar el DOM, entonces al principio no me salen reusltados, cuando selecciono filtros para que hayan suficientes para mostrar el paginador, le hago click en la página 2 y al hacer esto: `productos?page=2` me imprime el html de la página en #filtrados pero sin resultados.

Os muestro también las rutas:

```
Route::post('/productos', 'app@filtros');
Route::get('/productos', 'app@productos')->name('app.productos');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al final era más facil de lo que parecia. Resulta que como las dos rutas son /productos pero una si es GET y la otra POST, en el ajax de la paginación había que poner POST en lugar de GET y añadirle los headers.

```
function getData(page){
      $.ajax(
      {
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
          url: '?page=' + page,
          type: "POST",
          datatype: "html"
      }).done(function(data){
          $("#filtrados").empty().html(data);
          location.hash = page;
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert('No response from server');
      });
  }
```